# "Index Out Of Range" error When adding and removing from a List

Tags: c#, multithreading, list

I want to add/remove to a List but i got "Index Out Of Range" exception. In my code im adding data 2 times in a second until 10. And im removing them by using threads. Also im using Semaphores for blocking. I want to use 3 threads concurrently.

Here is my code

```
 class Program
{
    private static Thread[] threads = new Thread[3];
    private static Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(3, 3);
    private static List<string> messagesList = new List<string>();
    private static readonly object _kilit = new object();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread addData = new Thread(AddData);
        addData.Start();

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            threads[j] = new Thread(AddComma);
            threads[j].Name = "thread_" + j;
            threads[j].Start();
        }
    }
    public static void AddData()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            messagesList.Add("data");
            messagesList.Add("data");                
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }

    }
    public static void AddComma()
    {
        sem.WaitOne();
        while (true) {                
            if (messagesList.Count > 0)
            {

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Entering to Critical section");
                    int averageIndex = messagesList[0].ToString().Length / 2; // Here is the error
                    string msg = messagesList[0].ToString().Substring(0, averageIndex) + "," + messagesList[0].ToString().Substring(averageIndex);
                    Console.WriteLine(msg);
                    messagesList.RemoveAt(0);
                    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Exiting from Critical Section");                                   

            }             
        }
        sem.Release();

    }
}
```

Comment: What line is the exception thrown on?

Comment: You have race condition, checking for `Count` and using index are not atomic. You can fix it by combining them (and also `RemoveAt`) into a `lock`.

Comment: `List<T>` is not thread-safe. Use a [thread-safe collection instead.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/)

Comment: You are modifying a non-threadsafe collection from multiple threads simultaneously, which is practically guaranteed to cause errors and unexpected behaviour. You need to properly synchronise write access to your list, or use a concurrent collection.

Comment: You're trying to read from an empty list. In the line `int averageIndex = messagesList[0].ToString().Length / 2;` you probably haven't set any values yet. Check for messageList.Count

Comment: Calls between AddData and AddComma are not protected by locks - you're just controlling access from your threads within the AddComma method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allowing three threads to run at the same time:

```
new Semaphore(3, 3);
```

So your `Semaphore` isn't helping you really, because you're not really blocking. So you still have the problem where, for example, you could have one message left in the list, but 3 threads all evaluate `messagesList.Count > 0` to be `true`. One of those threads is going to remove the item from the list first, which will cause the other two to throw an exception.

There are better ways to do this. For lists, I like using [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim), which has read locks and write locks. It lets all threads read, but blocks everyone once you take a write lock. There is an example of how to use it in the documentation.

Comment: What if i want to 3 threads enter to the write Locks without conflicting? is there any way to do this by using Lists?

Comment: Yes, use the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` that I linked to. Read over that documentation.

Comment: Sorry, document tells us that method allows only one thread for writing and many threads for reading. Look at this : " Use ReaderWriterLockSlim to protect a resource that is read by multiple threads and written to by one thread at a time. ReaderWriterLockSlim allows multiple threads to be in read mode, allows one thread to be in write mode with exclusive ownership of the lock, and allows one thread that has read access to be in upgradeable read mode, from which the thread can upgrade to write mode without having to relinquish its read access to the resource."

Comment: Exactly. That's the only way it can work. The exception you were getting is because you allowed more than one thread to write at the same time.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't have more than one thread *running* - they just can't be *writing* at exactly the same time. Each thread should take the write lock as *just before* it writes, and release it *immediately after* it finishes writing.

Comment: I should be more specific: the exception you were getting was because you were letting threads *read* the list *while another was writing to it*. That's what `ReaderWriterLockSlim` prevents.

Comment: Firstly thank you for helping Gabriel, but if other threads are waiting to write/delete, why am i using others? I want to use 3-4 threads for deleting from the list. If will they wait, so i dont need them , it is same result  using 1 or 3-4 threads. I need to many threads for deleting from list at the same time without waiting to deleting order. For example i have 100 datas in a list and 5 threads to delete from the list. All 5 threads have to delete 20 items at the same time and without waiting each others. Thank you...

Comment: Gabriel i understand, other threads wont enter to the write block but they can do other processes. Thank you for helping. Happy Coding...

Comment: Yes exactly. You've got it now!

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1: you allow 3 concurrent threads to access the list, should be new Semaphore(1, 1);

Problem 2: sem.Release() is never called (unreachable code due to while(true)) so you have to move sem.WaitOne() to be first statement inside while block and sem.Release() to be the last line inside while block

Working code:

```
class Program
{
    private static Thread[] threads = new Thread[3];
    private static Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1, 1);
    private static List<string> messagesList = new List<string>();
    private static readonly object _kilit = new object();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread addData = new Thread(AddData);
        addData.Start();

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            threads[j] = new Thread(AddComma);
            threads[j].Name = "thread_" + j;
            threads[j].Start();
        }
    }
    public static void AddData()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            messagesList.Add("data");
            messagesList.Add("data");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }

    }
    public static void AddComma()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            sem.WaitOne();
            if (messagesList.Count > 0)
            {

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Entering to Critical section");
                int averageIndex = messagesList[0].ToString().Length / 2; // Here is the error
                string msg = messagesList[0].ToString().Substring(0, averageIndex) + "," + messagesList[0].ToString().Substring(averageIndex);
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
                messagesList.RemoveAt(0);
                Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Exiting from Critical Section");

            }
            sem.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Key thing is that one thread accesses the list at a given moment in time. All threads will take turns in accessing the list.